# Text to url parameter android app

Tags: android, url, text, parameters

I trying to do an app to query orders of my company. It's the layout:
https://ibb.co/mh8EOH

It's my code:

```js
#public class Orders extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText query; // declare here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Orders);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId1);
        String query = et.getText().toString();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Webview.class);
                i.putExtra("url", "https://mysite/query?order="+query);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

So... in android studio is showed "Variale 'query' is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final"

What's wrong? I wanna use input text to pass parameter to url.

Comment: add `final` to String query = et.getText().toString(); so it looks like  `final String query = et.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Declare your  String `query` variable as `final String query;`

or make it global like  this

```
public class Orders extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et; 
    String url="";
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Orders);

         btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        et  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId1);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                url = et.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Webview.class);
                    i.putExtra("url", "https://mysite/query?order="+url);
                    startActivity(i);
                    }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: @duggu pleaae check this line in OP question `String query = et.getText().toString();`

Comment: have you check OP image which post in question ? I am not here to fight with you just here for rectifying so do not take anything personally and ignore ...

Comment: @duggu sure sir

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get `edittext` value inside `onclick listener` like below :-

```
        et  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String query = et.getText().toString();
                if(!query.isEmpty()) { 
                     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Webview.class);
                     i.putExtra("url", "https://mysite/query?order="+url);
                     startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```